# Prove that, if $A, B$ are normed vector spaces then $(A\times B, \|\cdot \|)$ is a normed vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, infinite-matrices

I would like to understand what I must prove. Can you help me with this?

**Question:** Prove that, if $A, B$ are normed vector spaces then $(A\times B, \|\cdot \|)$ is a normed vector space.

**Note:** Note that $A, B$ are infinite-dimensional normed vector spaces.

**My question:** First, I must prove 8 properties of vector space, then how do I formalize, ie, how do I define what I want to prove? I want to prove that this vector space is only normalized with the sum, maximum and Euclidean norm. How do I prove that these norms are equivalent in a infinite-dimensional space like this? How do I define what I want to prove?

The norms mentioned are

- sum $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|_A+\|y\|_B$;
- maximum $\|(x,y)\|= \max(\|x\|_A,\|y\|_B)$;
- euclidian $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{\|x\|_A^2+\|y\|_B^2}$;

Is there any way to prove the equivalence between this norm, than I can use just one to prove that $(A\times B, \|\cdot\|)$ is a normed space instead prove for these three norms?

I would like some help to understand the statement and correctly define everything I have to prove. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The title makes no sense...

Comment: How can I change? If you downvote, please let me correct first. Do not downvote.

Comment: I am not the downvoter. I am just saying that a bilinear transformation cannot be a vector space...

Comment: Ok, thanks I will edit the title, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused what $\mathcal B$ and $C$ have to do with the problem since they don't appear in the conclusion.  Also the norm isn't defined.  Is some part of the problem's preamble missing?

Comment: You're write. I will edit the preamble.

Comment: Why downvotes?  (I was not one of them.)  For help figuring that out, see this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

Comment: @GEdgar I didn't understand downvotes!! It makes me sad. Why they can't send a comment of what they think it is wrong? Would be friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work. Let $\pi_A\colon A\times B\to A$ and $\pi_B\colon A\times B\to B$ the projections on the spaces $A$ respectively $B$. Observe, these are linear mappings.

Define a norm on $A\times B$ by $$ \|x\|_{A\times B} := \|\pi_A(x)\|_A+\|\pi_B(x)\|_B.$$

Then one can easily show, that it fulfills all three axioms of a norm. Of course, it is not the only one.

For example, we would like to show, that $\|(x,y) \|_\max:=\max(\|x\|_A,\|y\|_B)$ and $\|(x,y) \|_1:=\|x\|_A+\|y\|_B$ are equivalent.

If $\|x\|_A\geq \|y\|_B$, then we have $\|(x,y) \|_\max=\|x\|_A$
$$
\|(x,y) \|_\max=\|x \|_A\leq \|(x,y) \|_1=\|x\|_A+\|y\|_B\leq 2\|x\|_A=2\|(x,y) \|_\max.
$$
Hence, $\|(x,y) \|_\max\leq  \|(x,y) \|_1\leq 2\|(x,y) \|_\max$

Comment: Thanks very much. Looks like good idea. Do know how to prove the equivalence between that two norms?

Comment: Someone downvoted my question and your answer. Note that I don't have reputation to do this so. I don't understand why people do this. It is better send a comment, than I can edit. :(

Comment: Hello :) i don't know :D But now my answer is obsolete, i will edit it :)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. :)